# ORA-12154: TNS: could not resolve the connect identifier specified

Tags: oracle-xe

I installed Oracle Express.

After opening port 1521 in my Firewall I am able to do a successful:
tnsping xe.

But when I run:
SQL> connect system
or
system user:>sqlplus system
I get "ORA-12154: TNS: could not resolve the connect identifier specified".

This happens both locally for "system" and over TCP for "system@xe".

I've been fighting with this for a day and a half.
There seems to be no answer.

Here was my original listener:

```
----------------------------------

SID_LIST_LISTENER =
  (SID_LIST =
    (SID_DESC =
      (SID_NAME = PLSExtProc)
      (ORACLE_HOME = C:\oraclexe\app\oracle\product\11.2.0\server)
      (PROGRAM = extproc)
    )
    (SID_DESC =
      (SID_NAME = CLRExtProc)
      (ORACLE_HOME = C:\oraclexe\app\oracle\product\11.2.0\server)
      (PROGRAM = extproc)
    )
  )

    LISTENER =
      (DESCRIPTION_LIST =
        (DESCRIPTION =
          (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = IPC)(KEY = EXTPROC1))
      (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = NETEDELLLPTP-106)(PORT = 1521))
    )
  )

DEFAULT_SERVICE_LISTENER = (XE)= (XE)

--------------------------------------------
```

I changed to this:

---

```
SID_LIST_LISTENER =
  (SID_LIST =
    (SID_DESC =
       (SID_NAME = XE)
       (ORACLE_HOME = C:\oraclexe\app\oracle\product\11.2.0\server)
    )
    (SID_DESC =
      (SID_NAME = PLSExtProc)
      (ORACLE_HOME = C:\oraclexe\app\oracle\product\11.2.0\server)
      (PROGRAM = extproc)
    )
    (SID_DESC =
      (SID_NAME = CLRExtProc)
      (ORACLE_HOME = C:\oraclexe\app\oracle\product\11.2.0\server)
      (PROGRAM = extproc)
    )
  )



-------------------------------------------
```

That doesn't really seem to matter one way or another.
I can still ping but not connect either way.

Here is my tnsnames.ora:

---

```
XE =
  (DESCRIPTION =
    (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = NETEDELLLPTP-106)(PORT = 1521))
    (CONNECT_DATA =
      (SERVER = DEDICATED)
      (SERVICE_NAME = XE)
    )
  )

EXTPROC_CONNECTION_DATA =
  (DESCRIPTION =
    (ADDRESS_LIST =
      (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = IPC)(KEY = EXTPROC1))
    )
    (CONNECT_DATA =
      (SID = PLSExtProc)
      (PRESENTATION = RO)
    )
  )

ORACLR_CONNECTION_DATA = 
  (DESCRIPTION = 
    (ADDRESS_LIST = 
      (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = IPC)(KEY = EXTPROC1)) 
    ) 
    (CONNECT_DATA = 
      (SID = CLRExtProc) 
      (PRESENTATION = RO) 
    ) 
  )
```

I've also restarted both services:
OracleServiceXE
and
OracleXETNSListener
a bunch of times after trying each suggestion like:
alter statements.
I just can't get it to work.

One more thing:
When I do a:
lsnrctl status xe,
I expect to get this as someone else here who has set this up correctly gets:

```
Service "xe" has 1 instance(s).
  Instance "xe", status READY, has 1 handler(s) for this service...
```

I was not getting this, but I think after the change noted above for listener.ora I get:
So now I have two instances of xe which is different:

```
Service "XE" has 2 instance(s).
  Instance "XE", status UNKNOWN, has 1 handler(s) for this service...
  Instance "xe", status READY, has 1 handler(s) for this service...
```

But at least the lower case xe instance looks correct.
I don't know where the upper case XE instance is coming from.

Also different from correct version (End Point Summary:
mine:

```
Listening Endpoints Summary...
  (DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=tcp)(HOST=NETEDELLLPTP-106)(PORT=1521)))
  (DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=tcp)(HOST=NETEDELLLPTP-106)(PORT=8080))(Presen
tation=HTTP)(Session=RAW))
  (DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=tcp)(HOST=127.0.0.1)(PORT=1521)))
```

Correct:

```
Listening Endpoints Summary...
  (DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=ipc)(PIPENAME=\\.\pipe\EXTPROC1ipc)))
  (DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=tcp)(HOST=Kiev-win)(PORT=1521)))
  (DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=tcp)(HOST=Kiev-win)(PORT=8080))(Presentation=HTTP)(Session=RAW))
```

Comment: I figured out my problem was that I had an '@' character in my password.
I fixed with these statements:</br>
1) my account was locked so I had to start with:</br>
SQL> ALTER User [username like system] account unlock;</br>
2) then change my password</br>
SQL> ALTER User system identified by newpassword;</br>

Remember to include the semicolon ate the end (;) or it goes to the next line and displays 2 with a blinking cursor waiting for you to finish the command.

Comment: sam, u should post your answer..

Answer (score 1):

The problem is (as you said) an @ character in your password. Oracle doesn't seem to like special characters like @ or !

To resolve, open up the SQL command line prompt, either from "Run SQL Command Line" in the start menu, or by opening up the command prompt and running

```
sqlplus
```

Then do

```
connect / as sysdba
alter user system identified by <newPassword>
```

HTH